# How to validate email id in alphanumeric

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to validate email to access alphanumeric characters

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function checkField(email)
{
if (/[^0-9a-bA-B\s]/gi.test(email.value))
{
alert ("Only alphanumeric characters and spaces are valid in 
this field");
email.value = "";
email.focus();
return false;
}
}
</script>
```

it must contain  alphabets and numerics ex:`"test123@gmail.com","admin890@gmail.com" , "abc456@gmail.com"`  .. how can rewrite this code.??      [image]

Comment: i want to validate email id

Comment: regular_exp = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
To validate email use this regular exp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am matching two reg exp as i am not sure how to combine them but it works only for alphanumeric

```
<form method="post" name="client_form" id="client_form"> <input name="email" id="email" type="text" value="" class="formq" tabindex="1" style="width:200px" autocomplete="off" onblur="checkField(this.value)"/>
</form>
<script>
function checkField(email){ 
console.log(email);
      var reg_exp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
      var chk = reg_exp.test(email);
      var checkalphanumeric = email.split("@");
      var alphanumeric_chk = /^(\d+[a-z]|[a-z]+\d)[a-z\d]*$/i;
      var check2 = alphanumeric_chk.test(checkalphanumeric[0]);
      console.log(check2);
      if(chk && check2){
          alert("valid");
      } else { 
          alert("Only alphanumeric characters and spaces are valid in this field"); 
      }
}
</script>
```

Here is what happens on 123@gmail.com
[image]

Comment: its not working..allways showing this alert

Comment: try using console.log(email); inside the function start to see what exactly you are sending to the function. Also can you show me your full validation code ?

Comment: <script type = "text/javascript">
 function checkField(email) {
var reg_exp = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  if(reg_exp.test(email)){
  // valid email
 } else {
alert("Only alphanumeric characters and spaces are valid in this field");
return false;
 }
 }</script>
<form method="post" name="client_form" id="client_form">
<input name="email" id="email" type="text" value="" class="formq"  tabindex="1" style="width:200px" autocomplete="off" onblur="checkField(this)"/></form>

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ra85j/141/ here is fiddle for you

Comment: check my edited answer

Comment: it works .,but i want result valid when the value is alphanumeric only ex:"abc123@gmail.com"..don't work in  alphabets(123@gmail.com) or numerics(abc@gmail.com)

Comment: check again...now it matches only alphanumeric..

Comment: sry..its again working in  alphabets and numerics separately .i need it combined result here is the example::abc1234@gmail.com

Comment: no it doesn't work  in alphabets and numerics separately .. working only for alphanumerics fds3242@gmail.com, d3sd3@gmail.com etc

Comment: can u check 123@gmail.com

Comment: I have added the screenshot too

Comment: me too ..but the result is valid..pls check

Comment: lol how is it happening :D send me your fiddle link

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ra85j/141/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ra85j/142/  check now and mark my answer as accepted .. thanks  Also even if you just create new html file and copy my answer to that and try running that it would have been done already because my answer too is working.

Comment: ya its working ...but result have some problm.if "abc1@gmail.com","123a@gmail.com"shows wrong but actually its true..and " abc12@gmail.com","123as@gmail.com" its working properly.

Comment: after numeric or alphabets single word or letter shows wrong ex:"abcd5@gmail.com","1234a@gmail.com".,and other all conditions working correctly.

Comment: Please help youself thank you !

Comment: realy thank you for helping  me..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ra85j/164/ try this :) I also edited my answer .... alphanumeric_chk updated to alphanumeric_chk = /^(\d+[a-z]|[a-z]+\d)[a-z\d]*$/i;

Comment: thank you its working..and this is what i want..

Comment: I am glad it helped !